# Share Child Record When parent record is shared

Tags: owd, sharing-rule, apex-sharing, criteria-based-sharing

I have two Object Let's say Object A and Object B, Both are related with Lookup relationship, and Both are set to Private In OWD setting.

Now When I share parent record I would like to share all it's child records also.

Is there any way I can achieve this, and I want that relationship to be Lookup only I don't want Master-Detail Relationship.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways you can do the sharing on child records,

1. [Manual Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=granting_access_to_records.htm&language=en)
2. [Apex Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) - Create a custom button on Master Object. On click of that button query the child record and used the apex sharing to share the child records.

You can vote for an idea [Sharing Settings for Lookup Relationships like Controlled by Parent](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jtLyAAI)